# Xcode 6 beta - Null error

Tags: ios, xcode6

While working with Xcode beta, I keep getting this error when trying to run the code in simulator.

[image]

After cleaning the application & running, it works fine.

However, can someone help as to why this is happening.

Comment: It's in beta, raise a bug with the bug reporter with instructions on how you're reproducing it.

Comment: Whilst yes this is related to the `xcode IDE` it is specific to `xcode 6` so I have switched the tag. As far as the issue goes I would do as `Jeff` has said and raise a bug report. Not sure why this has -1 though as it seems like a genuine question so +1 from me.

Comment: It is only related to the Beta of Xcode 6 I would guess.

Comment: @ViktorLexington this is still a genuine question that fills all the criteria for stackoverflow so doesn't deserve 2 downvotes and a vote to close, so who has downvoted and who has voted to close please state why.

Comment: Haha, no I didn't downvote nor was my comment on the downvote. It was related to the tag change. But it makes sense either way.

Comment: @ViktorLexington Oh ok, unfortunately there was no `xcode 6 beta` tag and I'm not going to create one for a beta as it will just get removed instantly.

Comment: @Jeff: Already done that!! Cheers.

Comment: @Popeye: Yeah I tried tagging it under Xcode 6 beta, & dint find one.

Comment: @footyapps27 there is no point in there being an `xcode 6 beta` tag as once the beta is over it would become redundant, tags should be created when it will be able to be continually used and will not knowingly expire. There could possibly be a use for an `xcode beta` tag but not one specific to a certain `xcode` version, so the `xcode 6` tag should do here.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this working?**") must include *sufficient detail to reproduce the problem*. The way this is phrased will make it difficult to debug and impossible to search for when others encounter the issue.

Comment: @Veedrac I tend to disagree this is a genuine problem and I have managed to replicated so it does include enough detail to reproduce. I'm all up for closing logs when they need closing but this one definitely doesn't

Comment: @Popeye There are two problems to note. Firstly, there is no method given of reproducing the problem. Even if you *can* reproduce it, the question does not state how. The second is that the relevant search terms appear only implicitly in the image, making it impossible to find. Both of these can be fixed with an edit, though, if you're up for it. Note that even if the problem happens sporadically, *this needs to written down so that it can be found in a search*. Also note that `"enter image description here"` is a good  place to put search keywords (please still use sentence fragments though).

Comment: @Veedrac sure you might not be able to read it but it sure does read like there is a method to reproduce it to me, `"I keep getting this error when trying to run the code in simulator."` So guess what I just ran this thing called the simulator and I get the same issue. It wasn't hard to reproduce at all. There were no steps except for starting a new project and running it. So it clearly is just an issue with the simulator which can be resolved by just reporting the bug. I don't see how they could have state how to replicate it any clearer, **RUN IN SIMULATOR** and boom replicated.

Comment: @Popeye "the code"? What code? If it's important and easy to reproduce, just edit the question. I'm sure then it'll open quickly and we can clear up the comments.

Comment: @Veedrac there is no edit required all I did to reproduce this was start a new project and run it and on the very first time I got this error. There is nothing else to add to this users question if you'd actually attempted to read the question and reproduce then you would have reproduced, and you can tell you haven't bothered trying otherwise your comments would have been much different. If you don't want to bother helping this person that's fine but some of us are trying to help.

Comment: @Popeye I *have* read the question and I stand by [both of my points that I have mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141123/xcode-6-beta-null-error?noredirect=1#comment37292394_24141123). You have barely addressed the first and haven't addressed the second. The close reason is explicit in what is required.